# Basic Memory Game Java

Tags: java, arrays, memory

I'm doing this memory Game and I can't seem to figure out the algorithm for matching the cards.

Like if two cards are the same, it gets disabled else hide the cards again.

Every time I click a card, it stays open and when I randomly select another card, for some reason the other ones closes again.

```
import java.awt.*;
import java.awt.event.*;
import javax.swing.*;

public class MemGame extends JFrame implements ActionListener
{
GridLayout three = new GridLayout(4,4);

String dolls[]= {"Ugly1.jpg","Ugly1.jpg","Ugly2.jpg","Ugly2.jpg","Ugly3.jpg","Ugly3.jpg","ugly4.jpg","Ugly4.jpg","Ugly5.jpg","Ugly5.jpg","Ugly6.jpg","Ugly6.jpg","Ugly7.jpg","Ugly7.jpg","Ugly8.jpg","Ugly8.jpg"};
JButton button[]= (new JButton[dolls.length]);
int current,shuffle,trans;
int check=0;
int holder[]=new int [2];

String container[]={"",""};

public MemGame()
{       
    Container c = getContentPane();
    c.setLayout(three);

        for(current=0;current<dolls.length;current++)
        {

            int shuffle=(int)(Math.random()*dolls.length);
            String hold=dolls[current];
            dolls[current]=dolls[shuffle];
            dolls[shuffle]=hold;

        }

        for(int x=0;x<dolls.length;x++)
        {   
            button[x]=new JButton();
            c.add(button[x]);
            button[x].addActionListener(this);
        }

    setVisible(true);
    setSize(500,500);
}
public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e)
{
        for(int x=0;x<dolls.length;x++)
        {   
            if(e.getSource()==button[x])
            {
                button[x].setText("");
                button[x].setIcon(new ImageIcon(dolls[x]));
                button[x].setEnabled(false);

            //This is where my problem starts.... I think

                check++;

                if(check==1)
                {
                    container[0]=dolls[x];
                    holder[0]=x;


                }
                if(check==2)
                {

                    container[1]=dolls[x];
                    holder[1]=x;

                }
                if(check==3)
                {
                    if(container[0].equals(container[1]))
                    {
                        button[holder[0]].setEnabled(false);
                        button[holder[1]].setEnabled(false);
                    }   
                    else
                    {
                        button[holder[0]].setEnabled(true);
                        button[holder[0]].setIcon(new ImageIcon());

                        button[holder[1]].setEnabled(true);
                        button[holder[1]].setIcon(new ImageIcon());

                    }
                    check=1;


                }
            }
        }
    }   

    public static void main (String args[])
    {
        new MemGame();
    }
}
```

Comment: Notice you have a typo in `dolls`:  `"ugly4.jpg"` instead of `"Ugly4.jpg"`.

Comment: yah i got that one hehe sorry :)

Answer (score 1):

Check for a valid combination on the second click, when `check` equals `2`, and re-enable the buttons if they do not match.

To redraw the screen while handling an event, this logic needs to run in a new thread, because the one responsible for updating the UI is already busy executing the event handler code.

```
@Override
public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
    Thread t = new Thread(() -> {
        for (int x = 0; x < dolls.length; x++) {
            if (e.getSource() == button[x]) {
                button[x].setText("");
                button[x].setIcon(new ImageIcon(dolls[x]));
                button[x].setEnabled(false);

                check++;
                if (check == 1) {
                    container[0] = dolls[x];
                    holder[0] = x;
                }
                if (check == 2) {
                    container[1] = dolls[x];
                    holder[1] = x;

                    try {
                        Thread.sleep(500L);
                    } catch (InterruptedException e1) {
                        e1.printStackTrace();
                    }

                    if (!container[0].equals(container[1])) {
                        button[holder[0]].setEnabled(true);
                        button[holder[0]].setIcon(new ImageIcon());
                        button[holder[1]].setEnabled(true);
                        button[holder[1]].setIcon(new ImageIcon());
                    }
                    check = 0;
                }
            }
        }
    });
    t.start();
}
```

Comment: Okay it's kinda working but it wouldn't show the second card I click thus when I play the game I would have a hard time to win

Comment: What I need is I need to reveal to cards, if they match , they get disabled or stay revealed else, they go back hidden